# C# Generic T assign type Tuple

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following class:

```
public static class Support<T>
{
    public static T CreateKeyNameJSONTT(IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> a, Action<T> b)
    {
        T result = default(T);

        try
        {
            foreach (var entry in a)
            {
              b((T)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFromInvariantString("[ \"" + entry.Item1 + "\", " + entry.Item2 + "\" ]"));
            }
            result = (T)Convert.ChangeType(true, typeof(T));
        }
        catch
        {
            result = (T)Convert.ChangeType(false, typeof(T));
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

I cant seem to call it correctly though:

```
var result = Support.CreateKeyNameJSONTT(List<Tuple<int, string>> list, (string entry) =>
{
});
```

The error i get is "Using the generic type List requires 1 argument"

Can anyone please help on this.  Nothing I do is working so I may be mis-understanding something.

Comment: You are passing `Tuple<int, string>` but method expects `Tuple<T,T>`. I.e. both tuple members should have same type

Comment: Side note: you are probably not showing line of code that causes the error. Servy's +1 answer shows fixes for code you shown, but it looks like you have something like `new List()` somewhere that causes error itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to use a `List<Tuple<int, string>>` because in the definition of the method you've said that the first parameter is: `IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>>`.  The key point here is that the first and second generic arguments to `Tuple` are the same; they can't be different in what you pass it when calling the method.

You could call it this way though:

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> list = null;
var result = Support<string>.CreateKeyNameJSONTT(list , (string entry) =>
{
});
```

That will compile.  (And fail at runtime, but that's another issue.)

Note that the generic argument needed to be supplied to `Support` in the form of: `Support<string>`.  The type cannot be inferred for a class's generic argument, only (potentially) for methods.  You could get type inference if you changed the definition to:

```
public static class Support
{
    public static T CreateKeyNameJSONTT<T>(...)
```

Comment: @adviner You can't really put much code in a comment; there's a fairly low char limit.  If your issue has been resolved as a result of this answer, feel free to just mark it and be done.  If it didn't, are you getting the same error, a different error, or what?  If it's the same problem, you can edit your new code into the question.  If it's not, it's possible you should be asking another question.

Comment: Thanks Servy you helped me understand it better.  I was able to fixed the code and updated my question to show the working code.

Comment: @adviner It is inappropriate to edit the code in the question to remove the issue that was the cause of the question.  Since this answer apparently was sufficient for you to answer the question, it should be fine to just leave all of the posts as they are.

Comment: Oh sorry I didnt know.  Hope you can revert it back.  going forward I will make sure not to do that.  Thanks for the help again

Comment: @adviner I already reverted it.  It's just a click of a button, as there is a revision history kept.